# register_shutdown_function not working when the mysql server doesn't respond

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo

I'm trying to execute the **register_shutdown_function** when Zend_Db (PDO_MYSQL) can't reach the mysql server 10.0.0.36 but it hangs **30 seconds** and then shows the next error:

> Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Se produjo un
> error durante el intento de conexión ya que la par (trying to connect
> via tcp://10.0.0.36:3306) in
> C:\AppServ\php5\pear\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 129
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 5 seconds exceeded in
> C:\AppServ\php5\pear\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 129

Hangs 30 seconds but I have a set_time_limit(5). Normally the shutdown function catchs all errors, FATAL ERROR inclusives, only fails in this case.

What's going on? How can I make the shutdown function fire, or the 5s time limit to be observed?

Comment: This is interesting. It potentially demonstrates a limitation in `set_time_limit` when blocked on external processes, and a possible flaw in `shutdown_function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in Zend_Db:

```
'adapter' => 'PDO...',
'params' => array(
    'username' => '...',
     //...
    'driver_options' => array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 5)
 );
```

Now it doesn't hang for 30 seconds, and the `shutdown_function` works again.